# Objective-C confusion naming ivars id

Tags: objective-c, instance-variables

So when creating an own class it's quite common to have an id ivar that usually acts as a unique identifier. But since in Objective-C there exists the id type this creates confusion for the compiler when I declare my ivar as int id;

So how do you declare your ivar pertaining to hold ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename the ivar:

```
int identifier;
int uniqueIdentifier;
int ident;
```

And the list goes on...

Comment: So does `int identificationNumber` or a thousand other things. :P